# How do I go about scraping IBM X-force Exchange to get the risk scores of all the IPs from a list?

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation

We regularly generate a report that gets us 10 IPs to check out. We manually check every IP on IBM X-force Exchange for the risk score and whois info, mainly the org it belongs to.
We do this process manually at work and I started wondering if I could do it using web-scraping instead. I tried using Beautiful soup to search for the risk score and org but haven't been able to.

This is the function that I created:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def fetch_risk_level(ip_address):
    """Fetches the risk level of an IP address from X-Force Exchange.

    Args:
        ip_address (str): The IP address to fetch the risk level for.

    Returns:
        str: The risk level of the IP address, or None if not found.
    """

    url = f"https://exchange.xforce.ibmcloud.com/ip/{ip_address}"
    response = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    risk_level_element = soup.find("div", class_="risklevelbar")

    if risk_level_element is not None:
        risk_score = risk_level_element.find("div", class_="scorebackgroundfilter numtitle").text
        return risk_score 
    else: 
        return None
```

It always returned None whatever I try.

I realized that BeautifulSoup is unable to get the entire html code of the page. Is it possible to do this at all since it seems to me that the website's nature itself is a bit different?

Answer (score 0):

`beautifulsoup` cannot see anything, because the data is loaded from external URL via Ajax requests.

To get the score of IP you can do for example:

```py
import requests

url = "https://exchange.xforce.ibmcloud.com/api/url/142.250.186.174"
headers = {"x-ui": "XFE"}

print(requests.get(url, headers=headers).json())
```

Prints:

```
{
    "result": {
        "url": "google.com",
        "cats": {"Search Engines / Web Catalogues / Portals": True},
        "score": 1,
        "categoryDescriptions": {
            "Search Engines / Web Catalogues / Portals": "This category contains search engines, Web catalogues and Web portals. Dating sites, Social Networking sites and Business Networking sites are not listed here but in their own categories."
        },
    },
    "tags": [],
}
```

Comment: It works well for the example you provided. But when I change the ip, it prints `{'error': 'Not Found.'}`
Here are some of the IPs:
`34.140.53.79,
148.139.64.164,
3.125.117.202`

Comment: @MalharShembekar I'd recommend to open Web Developer Tools -> Network Tab and reload the page to see what Ajax requests the page is doing.